# Removendo itens de uma lista

Tags: android, lista, arraylist

O caso é o seguinte, quando removo os dados da lista, quando o numero da cabeça é maior que o segundo fica tudo certo por exemplo:

```
List<a>
0 - ITEM A
1 - ITEM B (X) Exlui este!
2 - ITEM c
```

Funciona perfeitamente, porque a lista ainda tem dois itens, porém quando vou remover no caso o `ITEM A` que é a cabeça do vetor tenho problemas ele solta uma excepion no log.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Para excluir estou utilizando esta logica:

```
int i=0;
int views = listaOpcionais.size();
Boolean existeItem = false;
if (views > 0) {
   while (i < views) {
        if(listaOpcionais.get(i).getCodRestauranteOpcao() == cod){
            if(listaOpcionais.get(i).getQuantidade() - 1 == -1 || listaOpcionais.get(i).getQuantidade() - 1 == 0){
                listaOpcionais.remove(listaOpcionais.get(i));
            }else{
                listaOpcionais.get(i).setQuantidade(listaOpcionais.get(i).getQuantidade() - 1 );
                listaOpcionais.get(i).setVlTotal(listaOpcionais.get(i).getValorUnitario() * quantidade);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

O Erro esta ocorrendo nesta linha:

```
if(listaOpcionais.get(i).getCodRestauranteOpcao() == cod)
```

E acontecendo apenas quando exclui o primeiro índice da lista.

Comment: De onde está vindo o cod? que no caso é o id no banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código tem vários erros. Quando você usa "views" para guardar o tamanho do Array e ao mesmo tempo exclui elementos do Array dentro do loop, uma hora isso vai dar erro porque enquanto o tamanho do Array vai diminuindo, o seu "i" eventualmente ficará maior que o último índice do Array, visto que quem está condicionando o loop é "views", que guarda o tamanho inicial do Array.

A mesma lógica se aplica ao erro que você está tendo. Você remove um item do array, que provavelmente só deve ter 2 itens e agora passa a ter só 1, depois incrementa o "i" que passa a ser 1, mas o maior índice do seu Array agora é 0, pois só tem 1 elemento.